# SQL Select duplicate rows with specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have a table (JobLog) that contains data on products. I want to be able to check if some fields may have been resubmitted and entered twice but possibly have been processed before.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT A.ProductName, A.ProductCode, A.AmtHeld, A.Disposition
FROM 
    JobLog AS A 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ProductCode, AmtHeld
        FROM JobLog GROUP BY ProductCode, AmtHeld 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS B 
        ON (A.ProductCode = B.ProductCode) 
        AND (A.AmtHeld = B.AmtHeld)
```

And it outputs:

```
|ProductName | AmtHeld | ProductCode | Disposition|
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
| chocolate  | 123     | 500         | P          |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
| chocolate  | 123     | 500         | C          |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
| vanilla    | 355     | A30         | C          |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
| vanilla    | 355     | A30         | C          |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
```

Is there any way to have an additional parameter of where it would only output rows that have Disposition = P as part of the row? As in, I'd only want the output of the two chocolate products since one of them has a disposition of P but not the two vanilla since they both have a disposition of C (there is no P).

```
|ProductName | AmtHeld | ProductCode | Disposition|
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
| chocolate  | 123     | 500         | P          |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
| chocolate  | 123     | 500         | C          |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------|
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can put the condition right in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT A.ProductName, A.ProductCode, A.AmtHeld, A.Disposition
FROM JobLog AS A INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ProductCode, AmtHeld
     FROM JobLog
     GROUP BY ProductCode, AmtHeld 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
            SUM(IIF(DISPOSITION = 'P', 1, 0)) > 0
    ) AS B
    ON A.ProductCode = B.ProductCode AND 
       A.AmtHeld = B.AmtHeld
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `WHERE EXISTS` clause to your query to check for a product that has a `Disposition` value of `P` somewhere in the table:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM JobLog A1
              WHERE A1.ProductCode = A.ProductCode AND A1.Disposition = 'P')
```

Alternatively you could do another self join:

```
JOIN JobLog C
ON C.ProductCode = A.ProductCode AND C.Disposition = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your requirement can be met without using aggregation. You could simply use a `WHERE EXISTS` condition to ensure that there are at least two records for the current ProductCode/AmtHeld tuple, and that one of them has disposition P.

```
SELECT A.ProductName, A.ProductCode, A.AmtHeld, A.Disposition
FROM JobLog AS A 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM JobLog B
    WHERE 
        A.ProductCode = B.ProductCode 
        AND A.AmtHeld = B.AmtHeld
        AND A.Disposition <> B.Disposition
        AND (A.Disposition = 'P' OR B.Disposition = 'P') 
)
```

**[This DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k3t6yV6TXU3WvdA9PRjts4/1)** with your sample data returns :

```
| ProductName | ProductCode | AmtHeld | Disposition |
| ----------- | ----------- | ------- | ----------- |
| chocolate   | 500         | 123     | P           |
| chocolate   | 500         | 123     | C           |
```